# how to get the items name from listview after using intent with sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

i have two listviews each one of them is in different activity i want to send an item from the first listview to the other one by long click on it im using intent, im using string file to get the data it sends the item perfectly but its not saved to sqlite i dont know where is the problem please take a look at my code

```
First Activity(Main Activity):
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cc.class);
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID",l);// THIS ADDED
                    startActivity(intent);
                    fav_name = getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getString(getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fav_name+" Added To Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    return true;
                }

            });
```

```
Second Activity(cc):
                fav_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID", 0);

        manageFavouritesListView();


if (fav_id==0){


}



        getDataInCurrentLocaleById = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
            if (getDataInCurrentLocaleById.moveToFirst()) {
                fav_name = getDataInCurrentLocaleById.getString(getDataInCurrentLocaleById.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));


            }

        getDataInCurrentLocaleById.close();
        }


    private void manageFavouritesListView() {
        getDataInCurrentLocaleById = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
        if (favourites_adapter == null) {
            favourites_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.textview2,
                    getDataInCurrentLocaleById,
                    new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME},
                    new int[]{R.id.textview10},
                    0
            );
            listView.setAdapter(favourites_adapter);
            setListViewHandler(listView, true);
        } else {
            favourites_adapter.swapCursor(getDataInCurrentLocaleById);
        }
    }
```

```
Db_Sqlite:
    public Cursor getAllDataInCurrentLocale(Context context) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
        MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
        }
        csr.close();
        return mxcsr;
    }
    public Cursor getDataInCurrentLocaleById(Context context, long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String wherepart = FAVOURITES_COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,wherepart,args,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
        MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
        }
        csr.close();
        return mxcsr;
    }

    /* This getting columns from Cursor into String array (no BLOB handleing)*/
    public String[] convertCursorRow(Context context, Cursor csr, String[] columnsToConvert) {
        String[] rv = new String[csr.getColumnCount()];
        for (String s: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            boolean converted = false;
            for (String ctc: columnsToConvert) {
                if (csr.getType(csr.getColumnIndex(s)) == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB) {
                    //........ would have to handle BLOB here if needed (another question if needed)
                }
                if (ctc.equals(s)) {
                    rv[csr.getColumnIndex(s)] = StringResourcesHandling.getStringByName(context,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(s)));
                    converted = true;
                }
            } if (!converted) {
                rv[csr.getColumnIndex(s)] = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(s));
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

    }
```

i dont where is the problem please help me thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
You should notify the adapter that data changed.

    private void manageFavouritesListView() {
            getDataInCurrentLocaleById = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
            if (favourites_adapter == null) {
                favourites_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,
                        R.layout.textview2,
                        getDataInCurrentLocaleById,
                        new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME},
                        new int[]{R.id.textview10},
                        0
                );
                listView.setAdapter(favourites_adapter);
                favourites_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                setListViewHandler(listView, true);
            } else {
                favourites_adapter.swapCursor(getDataInCurrentLocaleById);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your response but i tried your way and it did not work